# Security Setup for Symfony2 Without login

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony, authorization

I have been trying to get setup with symfony2 for a while now and it has been going well for quite a while, but I've hit a bit of a snag. I can't figure out how to get my security setup. At our institution, we have a installation of cas (single sign on) and a static class that deals with all of the authentication stuff. It is called gatekeeper. Gatekeeper does all of the role checking and username login stuff. I want to be able to use the authorization stuff of symfony2, but none of the authentication stuff. Is this possible? I have read the documentation but it seems like those things are too tightly bound to be separated. Does anyone have any insights on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using your Gatekeeper class for authentication before the request hits the firewall you can create a "pre-authenticated" (i.e. authentication happens before the firewall) listener by extending [AbstractPreAuthenticatedListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractPreAuthenticatedListener.php) and implementing `getPreAuthenticatedData()`:

```
class GatekeeperListener extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedListener
{
    protected function getPreAuthenticatedData(Request $request)
    {
        return array(
            Gatekeeper::getCurrentUsername(), // username
            '',                               // credentials
        );
    }
}
```

You will need to create a security factory in order to introduce a new authentication listener to the system. This process is described in this cookbook article:

[How to create a custom Authentication Provider: The Factory](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-factory)

Your `security.yml` should look something like this:

```
security:
    factories:
        - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.yml"

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: .
            gatekeeper: true
```

Comment: Kris, thanks for your reply. I am finally getting around to this and I have an additional question. Is the credentials part of the returned array a comma separated string of roles or an array of roles? Thanks for your helpful response. I don't think the PreAuthenicatedListener is mentioned anywhere in the Symfony2 documentation (besides the API).

Comment: The second item in that array would be the user's password, but you can just return an empty string.

Comment: Ok Kris, I think I have more of it working, but now I keep getting "A token was not found in the SecurityContext" exception. Where do the tokens get inserted into the security context? Do I need to be doing that, or should that theoretically be happening by my user providers?

Comment: I figured it out, a lot of the parameters for constructors have changed since the last documentation creation. They really need to get that documentation up to speed.